# What code can I use for min, max and average for java programming without arrays?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I'm doing a project for my programming class and I'm stuck. I've written the code but I can't figure out how to implement the min, max and average into the class. We haven't learned about arrays yet and I just need a good nudge in the right direction. Please help!

The exercise reads: Write an application that allows a user to enter any number of student test scores until the user enters 999. If the score entered is less than 0 or more than 100, display an appropriate message and do not use the score. After all the scores have been entered, display the number of scores entered, the highest score, the lowest score, and the arithmetic average.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class TestScoreStatistics {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double score;
    double max;
    double min;
    double average;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter in test scores: ");
    score = keyboard.nextDouble();
    while(score >= 0 || score <= 100) {
        if(score >= 101 || score <= 0.9)
            System.out.println("The score must be between 0 - 100");
        else
            System.out.println("Please enter in test scores or type 999 to calculate final scores: ");
            score = keyboard.nextDouble();



        if(score == 999)
            System.out.println("The maximum score is - " + max + ".");
            System.out.println("The minimum score is - " + min + ".");
            System.out.println("The average score is - " + average + ".");          
    }   
}
```

}

I'm not looking for the direct answer, I just want confirmation that I'm using the right type of loop and what code should I use for the math part. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `while(score >= 0 || score <= 100) {` unless you somehow enter a score of NaN, this is always true.

Comment: @AndyTurner:   One *could* send `"NaN"` as a string and it would be `Double.NaN`.

Comment: How do they expect you to calculate an average without holding all of the numbers in an array?

Comment: @nitind you don't need an array to do that. You just need a sum and a count

Comment: @nitind:  You can keep a running sum and a count of how many numbers you've processed.  No need for an array.

Comment: I've been made aware of Java stream summaryStatistics today.  Give it a look: https://dzone.com/articles/using-java-stream-summary-statistics-snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate an average, you just need two variables, one for the sum of all the scores, and one for the number of scores. That shouldn't require arrays. Also, the min and max score values can be updated each time a score is input.